# Sanitize Blob Url in Angular 4 by DomSanitizer

Tags: angular, angular-dom-sanitizer

The idea is to embed a pdf file on angular side that is being returned by node express server in blob form.
[image: file is returned in the form of blob]

After then i get the image and created a URL

```js
const file = new Blob([this.data], { type: 'application/pdf' });
this.fileUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file);
this.protectedUrl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(this.fileUrl);
```

And then after i use this in html

```html
<object ng-show="content" data="{{protectedUrl}}" type="application/pdf" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"></object>
```

[image: and then even after using the sanitizer angular is returning the cleaning url problem]

Comment: change it as [data]="protectedUrl" or [attr.data]="protectedUrl"

Comment: if i use <object  [data]="protectedUrl" type="application/pdf" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"></object>
this is giving the same error

Comment: after using 
<object [data]="{{protectedUrl}}" type="application/pdf" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"></object> it's giving Template Parsing Error

Answer (score 4):

It's working now by changing data to attr.data

```js
<object  [attr.data]="protectedUrl" type="application/pdf" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"></object>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issues for images and the solution was the following:

```
<img *ngIf="protectedUrl" [src]="protectedUrl" />
```

P.S. Just make sure that the data is ready before binding.

Comment: yes this was not an issue i just need to change data to attr.data
<div *ngIf="!loading">
  <object  [attr.data]="protectedUrl" type="application/pdf" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"></object>
</div>